# Exclude cell with 0 for mean calculation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the mean of a dataframe group by depth. The problem is that is using cells that are 0 because no data was taken at that depth.

My Df looks like the one on the picture. For example, there are some missing for 49m, so I want to do the mean with the values that aren't 0, but I cant get that.

[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Glw.png)

I have tried to replace those 0 for NaN with replace but still, when calculating the mean it uses the cells with 0

`file.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)`

Comment: What is `print (file.dtypes)` ? Because seem data are strings, then need `file.replace('file.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)', np.nan, inplace=True)` and convert values to numeric

Comment: I just tried, all data are float. Thx

Comment: So `file.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)` not replacing?

Comment: no, for some reason it isn't replacing the values so when calculating the mean it includes those 0.

Comment: Fixed, the replace function works. I spotted a problem before those lines that was causing not to have any 0. Thanks for your help Jezrael